# Running a MapAPI program in a emulator

Tags: android

### [I am referring to this Question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19447770/1083093)

---

- I am also trying to execute the MAP-API in my emulator
- I am not trying to use any other emulators like Genymotion
- I have also referenced google play store by importing to my eclipse
  here ::
  `<android-sdk-folder>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-s‌​ervices_lib
  library project`

---

**I also followed link and installed apk's through command line to my emulator for the fix like**

- vending-2.apk
- gms-2.apk
- maps-2.apk

---

I have no errors in the code as the code is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19447770/1083093) link

---

### Apparently my log reads as

```
10-19 14:02:00.369: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(435): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3265100 but found 2012110
```

*How to resolve this !*

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the Google Play services using the Android SDK Manager. Open the Android SDK Manager and expand the 'Extras' option. There you can see your 'Google Play Services' Revision. As of today the latest revision is 12. Probably you have to update your revision.

Comment: Try creating a new emulator with target API level 16 and test your app using it.